# MySql problem with save DATEDIFF in column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am writing a hotel database and I have a question about DATEDIFF func. I have a table with guest ID, arrival date, departure and I want DATEDIFF (departure, arrival) to write in another column in the same table. How can I do this? I tried to make two tables, but it worked once and when I added another guest,  each time a primary key duplication error popped up.

When I created empty column 'length' and I tried save select in this column then shows me error.
code:
    insert into reservations (length_of_stay) select DATEDIFF(departure, arrival) from reservations; 
error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`input_qt_plus`.`reservations`, CONSTRAINT `fk_reservations_guests` FOREIGN KEY (`guests_id_guests`) REFERENCES `guests` (`id_guests`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Tables:

This is a table with the guests:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `input_qt_plus`.`guests` (
      `id_guests` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `phone` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `id_num` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_guests`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And this is a table with a reservations:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `input_qt_plus`.`reservations` (
  `id_res` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guests_id_guests` INT NOT NULL,
  `arrival` DATE NOT NULL,
  `departure` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_res`),
  INDEX `fk_reservations_guests_idx` (`guests_id_guests` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reservations_guests`
    FOREIGN KEY (`guests_id_guests`)
    REFERENCES `input_qt_plus`.`guests` (`id_guests`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please add your table definition and the steps you took which caused the duplicate key error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: Hope it will work

```
INSERT INTO your_table (field1, field2, arrival, departure, length)
    VALUES (value1, value2, arrivalDate, departureDate, DATEDIFF(day,arrivalDate, departureDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're updating the same table you should reffer to it twice.
First add the column to the table (let's say you call it stay_for) and then update it like this -

```
update reservations R
inner join reservations R2
on R2.id_res = R.id_res
set R.stay_for =  DATEDIFF(R2.departure, R2.arrival);
```